# First order differential equation with coefficients depended on depended variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve first order differential equation where coefficient are depended on depended variable. For example, 
$$\frac {dy}{dt}+ay=bt$$

where $a$ is $1$ if $(y\lt 3)$,  and $a$ is $2$ if $(y\gt 3)$, and $b$ is $3$ for $(y\lt 3)$ and $b$ is $4$ for $(y\gt 4) $

Comment: Solve each of them separately and then glue the two at $y=3$. Probably  you mean $y>3$ instead of $y>4$.

Comment: @Isham Interesting comment... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an equation of the form

$$y'(t) + ay(t) = f(t)$$

And the solutions is given by

$$\large y(t) = \frac{1}{e^{\int a\ dt}}\left(\int e^{\int a\ dt}\ f(t)\ dt + C\right)$$

You can then adapt the solution to your cases.